# Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, cloud

Boa tarde.
Onde posso aprender sobre Firebase cloud functions para poder fazer minhas próprias funções ? 
eu preciso comecar do zero e nao encontro material nem um na internet com passo a passo. alguem pode me indicar videos em portugues sobre o assunto ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).